# Spring PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS transaction with read only, do you need to commit?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Sample code:

```
protected Session session() {
        return (Session) getEntityManager().getDelegate();
}

session().createCriteria( entityClass )
```

First call to session().createCriteria() complains that the session is closed if there are no transaction available.

So I create a readonly transaction using:

```
TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate( getTransactionManager() )
template.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS);
template.setReadOnly(true);

TransactionStatus status = getTransactionManager().getTransaction(template);
```

Do I need to commit this transaction: 
    getTransactionManager().commit(status);

The problem is that if this is committed, I am going to need another transaction later on for:

```
criteria.list();
```

and the problem with that is that the second time, it is a different transaction from the one that was used to get the session, and that results in an error. It will complain that it is already closed.

session().createCriteria and criteria.list must be used in the same transaction it seems. But my code has these in methods and therefore there is no nice way to ensure these methods will work separately unless the session.createCriteria transaction remains uncommitted.

Can I safely leave a transaction of TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS uncommitted? How many such transactions can I create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot leave it as uncomitted. Read only is more of a hint to the underlying transaction manager to disallow mutations in the current transaction context. If you need to access the same transaction later on as well maybe you need a change in design a bit. Why not open the transaction in the caller of your method and handle it there? Or instead try declarative or annotation based approach?

Comment: Yes, one option is to open it where it is called, which is the way I will opt for. I don't like the annotation based approach. What do you mean by declarative based approach?

Comment: declarative means AOP based using XML.

Comment: Ooh, ook. No, I like my way. I am actually passing a lambda a supportsTransaction method, so it is far better and nicer than the @Transactional way which is just mess if you ask me, with a bunch of rules on how they must be used destined to fail when a new stupid developer takes over. It's almost like learning all the quirks of Javascript and HTML all over again. I tried to hookup up AspectJ once but didn't work that time. I finally cracked method based lambda taking transactions though!

Comment: Btw, isn't there some autocommit functionality that will close such transactions?

Comment: Actually no. autocommit is not an 'on the fly' thing.

Comment: Do you know how one can enbale it?

Comment: this is done mostly in the jdbc connection string or the TX manager bean definitions. but any sane TX manager would override this automatically. It makes no sense to use autocommit and TX together.